# How do I create two different buttons in HTML that reveal two different images?

Tags: javascript, html, web

**I apologise profusely for the cursed images but I'm making this to annoy friends.**

I want to have two different buttons that will display two different images on my website.

(I am very new to HTML and Javascript so please forgive if its really simple.)

I have copied most of this from tutorials and then gone back and tweaked it to do what I want and have had great success apart from this, the first button works perfectly but the second one doesn't display anything and causes and error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
> at ShowTwerkingCrewmateMoreCursed (/script.js:12:11)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:41:64)

```js
function ShowTwerkingCrewmate() {
  var x = document.getElementById('TwerkingCrewmateButton');
  if (x.style.display == 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function ShowTwerkingCrewmateMoreCursed() {
  var x = document.getElementById('TwerkingCrewmateMoreCursedButton');
  if (x.style.display == 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="color: coral; background-color: lightblue;">
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!--
      This is how you write a comment
    -->

  <header>
    <nav>
    </nav>

    <h1 style="color:coral;">
      <center>
        The Website Header
      </center>
    </h1>
  </header>

  <main>

    <article>
      <section>
        <h3>
          Amogus sus
        </h3>

        <BUTTON ONCLICK="ShowTwerkingCrewmate()">Click me</BUTTON>
        <br>
        <DIV ID="TwerkingCrewmateButton" STYLE="display:none">
          <IMG SRC="TwerkingCrewmate.gif" style="max-height: 25%; max-width: 25%;"></IMG>
        </DIV>

        <BUTTON ONCLICK="ShowTwerkingCrewmateMoreCursed()">Don't click me</BUTTON>
        <br>
        <DIV ID="TwerkingCrewmateButtonMoreCursedButton" STYLE="display:none">
          <IMG SRC="TwerkingCrewmateMoreCursed.gif" style="max-height: 25%; max-width: 25%;"></IMG>
        </DIV>
      </section>
    </article>

    <article>
      <section>
        <br>
        <a href="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ"> Click me </a>
      </section>
    </article>

    <p>
      <b>
      This is a paragraph of text where there are a bunch of words that are in senctences that have meaning and ideas conveyed through them.
      </b>
    </p>

  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: The id of the second button in javascript doesn't match what you have in html.

Comment: `TwerkingCrewmateButtonMoreCursedButton` --> `TwerkingCrewmateMoreCursedButton`

Answer (score 2):

You were trying to get the value of an id that was non-existent: "TwerkingCrewmateMoreCursedButton". So I just replaced this id with the id value you defined in the HTML part.

```js
function ShowTwerkingCrewmate() {
  var x = document.getElementById('TwerkingCrewmateButton');
  if (x.style.display == 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function ShowTwerkingCrewmateMoreCursed() {
  var x = document.getElementById('TwerkingCrewmateButtonMoreCursedButton');
  if (x.style.display == 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="color: coral; background-color: lightblue;">
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!--
      This is how you write a comment
    -->

  <header>
    <nav>
    </nav>

    <h1 style="color:coral;">
      <center>
        The Website Header
      </center>
    </h1>
  </header>

  <main>

    <article>
      <section>
        <h3>
          Amogus sus
        </h3>

        <BUTTON ONCLICK="ShowTwerkingCrewmate()">Click me</BUTTON>
        <br>
        <DIV ID="TwerkingCrewmateButton" STYLE="display:none">
          <IMG SRC="TwerkingCrewmate.gif" style="max-height: 25%; max-width: 25%;"></IMG>
        </DIV>

        <BUTTON ONCLICK="ShowTwerkingCrewmateMoreCursed()">Don't click me</BUTTON>
        <br>
        <DIV ID="TwerkingCrewmateButtonMoreCursedButton" STYLE="display:none">
          <IMG SRC="TwerkingCrewmateMoreCursed.gif" style="max-height: 25%; max-width: 25%;"></IMG>
        </DIV>
      </section>
    </article>

    <article>
      <section>
        <br>
        <a href="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ"> Click me </a>
      </section>
    </article>

    <p>
      <b>
      This is a paragraph of text where there are a bunch of words that are in senctences that have meaning and ideas conveyed through them.
      </b>
    </p>

  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explained the problem and how you solved it

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the answer and put the explanation.